# Windows 10 on an old VAIO. Hypervisors?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, virtualization, sony-vaio, hypervisor

A classmate asked me to try to restore an old Sony Vaio laptop to working condition.
It's a VPCEE2E1E (model PCG-61611M) which originally came with Win7 Home and a built-in licence. The HDD is completely unsuable. I tried to make an image, and it failed, and then I tried a zero fill and it also failed. So I was planning on replacing it with an SSD, put some more RAM in it (comes with 3GB), and start from scratch with a win10 install, but it seems Sony never provided WIN10 drivers for it, and even the WIN7 ones they put out back then, have now been removed from the official support site.

So, I have the following options:

1. Install old windows7 on it and try the drivers found floating around in dubious sites.
2. Install windows10 and hope to make it work to some degree (it seems people are having problems with this).
3. Install some kind of hypervisor (which I never tried) to take care of the hardware and put windows 10 on top of it.
4. Install some easy enough Linux distro with ready to use windows software compatiblity.

Given the kind of user, I don't think sticking with old usupported win7, or a half assed install of win10, or trying to migrate to linux are particularly good options, so I find the idea of the hypervisor rather appealing, but I have no idea how to go about it. Is this a good idea, what options do I have?

The CPU on this thing is an AMD P320, if that has any relevance to what I'm getting into.

Comment: Windows 7 OEM devices don’t have “built-in” licenses.

Comment: Well, I'll take your word for it, as I don't know much about that. But the laptop has a windows license sticker on the underside. Maybe you actually have to type the key during installation, I don't know.

Comment: You actually did which is the reason it changed with Windows 8 and newer OEM devices

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't seem like a good idea. Hypervisors won't magically take care of hardware without something equivalent to their own drivers.

In many cases, a "bare metal" hypervisor (the kind that runs underneath the main OS) actually still **relies on the main OS** to handle most devices – e.g. when you have WHP (the Hyper-V hypervisor) installed, Windows will still see exactly the same devices as before, i.e. although *technically* a VM, it runs as a "privileged domain" that has nearly full hardware access.

For example, when a VM uses the network, it's not the 'hypervisor' of Hyper-V that actually sends the packets over your physical Ethernet interface – it still goes through the drivers in the "main" VM. Your GPU is just entirely handled by the main OS, which still needs the same GPU drivers it did before; things like ACPI (for power management among many other things) are still handled by drivers in the main OS.

The same applies to the Xen hypervisor, which almost always has a "dom0" as the main VM that deals with nearly all hardware access on behalf of other VMs.

Other hypervisors like ESXi are a full OS with their own drivers (and ESXi being server-oriented, it won't have anything to offer for an old laptop). KVM is not a stand-alone hypervisor – it only comes as part of the Linux kernel, so anything that says "KVM" actually means "a regular Linux that runs regular VMs".

So I would a) try to gather drivers from other sources, e.g. the [chipset drivers from AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/chipsets/amd-8-series-chipsets/880g), the GPU drivers from whoever made the iGPU, the various shady "driver download" websites, etc.; b) consider using Linux if the laptop is going to serve as just a web-browsing device.